# How do I use scipy.optimize.minimize to calculate the best missing 6 parameters of my function

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I got the task to calculate the optimal parameters for the following viscosity-formula: [Click here for the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UTLD.png)

Our Prof just gave us the hint to try out the scipy.optimize.minimize and the scipy.optimize.differential_evolution function on the square deviation ([The formula he gave us for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmqp8.png) and the Values in this formula are 3 real points that the viscosity-function should picture) of the viscosity formula. [Here's the Graph to imagine how the function should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1QRB.png)

So after giving my best on finding out how these functions work I gave up with differential_evolution because I couldn't make it work with my code so I focussed on the minimize function and thought I understood whats happening but I dont understand what I need to give the function as "guess" (x0 parameter) so it starts calculating the optimal values.

I got problems with getting the formula into python too, so I hope at least that's right.

My code is:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

def visc(x, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5):
  ergebnis = a0*np.exp(-a1*x) + a2*np.exp(-a3*x) + a4*np.exp(-a5*x)
  return ergebnis

def error(a):
  a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 = a
  ergebnis = (visc(40, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) - 39.3)**2 + (visc(50, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) - 26.9)**2 + (visc(100, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5) - 5.4)**2
  return ergebnis

print(optimize.minimize(error, (0.1, 5, 0.1, 5, 3, 5)))
```

So maybe I'm just very lost and the solution is very trivial but right now I'm really desperate because I'm just stuck in my task and I would appreciate if some Scipy Pro's could help me with that.

I never worked with scipy or numpy or any other module before so please be patient with me.

Thanks for helping!